# Factorization with Julia Symbolics package

Tags: julia

I am starting to use the Julia package [Symbolics](https://juliasymbolics.org/) for symbolic Maths but I can not figure out how to factorize a polynomial.

I want to get the same as with SymPy.

```
using SymPy
@vars x
factor(x^2 + 2x + 1)
```

that returns

```bash
       2
(x + 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, factorization of polynomials does not yet exist in Symbolics.jl.

In the docs, the phrase "factorization" is [only mentioned once, on the homepage](https://symbolics.juliasymbolics.org/stable/search/?q=factorization). There is a [page comparing SymPy and Symbolics.jl](https://symbolics.juliasymbolics.org/stable/comparison/), which includes a link to [this feature list on a GitHub issue](https://github.com/JuliaSymbolics/Symbolics.jl/issues/59), and factorization of polynomials hasn't been marked as complete.